# ¿Cómo traducir "Clickbait" al español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática

Clickbait es, de acuerdo a una definición informal en internet

> content whose main purpose is to attract attention and encourage visitors to click on a link to a particular web page.
>
> *Clickbait* is a **text or thumbnail link that is designed to entice users to follow that link** and read, view, or listen to the linked piece of online content. Click-bait headlines typically **aim to exploit the "curiosity gap"**, providing just enough information to make readers of news websites curious, but not enough to satisfy their curiosity without clicking through to the linked content
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickbait)

Es decir, un titular diseñado para atraer la curiosidad, para hacerte "picar" y pulsar un link (visitar una página web) con el propósito de atraer visitas. Que el contenido cumpla con lo prometido en el enlace *clickbait* (en términos de satisfacer la curiosidad, estar relacionado con lo prometido en dicho titular, etc.) ya es otro cantar.

Un ejemplo podrían ser los muchos videos de YouTube o artículos de diferentes medios como "10 trucos rápidos y sin esfuerzo para hacerte millonario (No te vas a creer el número 8)", "Ocho dietas milagro para perder peso comiendo lo que quieras", "20 señales de que tu pareja te engaña" que luego llevan a videos o artículos más o menos relacionados con el título, de dudosa calidad la mayor parte de las veces.

Estos titulares o enlaces suelen ser engañosos o desorientadores a propósito: "Madonna/El papa se muere!!<sub>(de ganas de visitar Murcia)</sub>. A veces son incluso erróneos a propósito (no están para nada relacionados con lo prometido, pero ya les has dado la visita a su web, así que no importa).

La entrada de wikipedia muestra que "clickbait" ha calado como anglicismo en español, dada la falta de una traducción apropiada. La palabra *click* no está registrada en el diccionario de la RAE (aunque sí lo están [*clic*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9SZ4Kat) y el verbo asociado [*clicar*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9SdJHbH)), y "bait" vendría a traducirse como "cebo" o "carnaza".

¿Cuál sería entonces una traducción apropiada para "clickbait" en español?

Comment: ¿Le has echado un ojo a la versión en español de la página de Wikipedia? Ahí salen varias opciones de traducción: ciberanzuelo, cibercebo, cebo de clics​ o anzuelo de clics. La que más me gusta es cibercebo, aunque se pierde el click del original anglosajón.

Comment: Sí, pero también vi que salen otros términos relacionados como likebait, linkbait, sharebait, tweetbait y esperaba que diferentes propuestas en las respuestas pudiesen ayudar también con esos términos similares (anzuelo de/para Likes? Cebo de Tweets?). Elegir "cebo" frente a "anzuelo" puede ser una preferencia personal y subjetiva, pero puede que otros términos incorporen otros vocablos que aclaren muy bien el término en español, y esperaba poder explorar eso un poco mediante múltiples respuestas en la pregunta.

Answer (score 8):

Pues creo que hay una palabra que lo define muy bien y es...

## cazaclics

Lo vi [recomendado en Twitter por @quimicefa](https://twitter.com/quimicefa/status/832275305050021892) y me pareció muy acertado, pues:

- incluye el verbo *cazar* que denota la metodología utilizada, parecida al de la jungla.
- incluye los *clics* que es lo que se pretende con esta técnica.

Answer (score 3):

La versión en español de la [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickbait) ofrece varias alternativas:

> ha sido traducido al español como «ciberanzuelo», «cibercebo»,​ «cebo de clics»​ o «anzuelo de clics»

En dicha página aparece enlazada una [encuesta](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/ciberanzuelo-la-alternativa-favorita-de-nuestros-seguidores-a-clickbait/) relacionada que hizo la Fundéu BBVA al respecto donde las traducciones preferidas fueron: **ciberanzuelo** (26%) y **cibercebo** (20%)

Aunque me gusta la palabra señalada por @fedorqui, mi predilecta es **cibercebo**, la cual tiene sus pros y sus contras.

Pro:

**cebo** es la traducción correcta para el término **bait**. Bait NO se corresponde en inglés con anzuelo (hook). El cebo es lo que se pone en el anzuelo para atraer a los peces. Es decir, no se trata de una cuestión de subjetividad sino de una cuestión de precisión en los términos traducidos, en este caso.

Podemos constatar esta afirmación si comparamos las definiciones que nos ofrecen el DRAE y el Cambridge Dictionary respectivamente

**[cebo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=84tl0z8%7C84u0vNx)**

> 1. m. **Comida** que se da a los animales para alimentarlos, engordarlos o atraerlos.
> 2. m. En la pesca, alimento, real o simulado, con que se **atrae** a los peces.

**[bait](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bait)**

> a small amount of **food on a hook** (= curved piece of wire) or in a
>   special device used to **attract** and catch a fish or animal

Además en relación a clickbait, el titular cortado, la imagen prometedora o lo que sea que te atrae a clicar es lo que recibe la denominación. Es un cebo para clics. El link es el anzuelo, es lo que te arrastra a otra página.

Imagen Prometedora ó Titular sesgado = cebo = bait.

Link = anzuelo = hook.

---

Pro:

**[ciber-](https://dle.rae.es/?id=98ULSyc)**

> 1. elem. compos. Indica **relación con redes informáticas**. *Ciberespacio, cibernauta.*

**ciber-** es un prefijo que suena bien a los nacidos en el siglo XX porque nos habla del futuro. De que ya están cerca los robocordones y los coches voladores.

Y como podeis apreciar por su definición añade a la palabra información muy relevante, el **donde** está puesto ese cebo: en las redes informáticas, en internet. Se pierde el clic pero ahora se puede usar para agrupar a todos esos neotérminos mencionados por @Diego: likebait, linkbait, sharebait, tweetbait ... Todo eso son cibercebos. Trampantojos cibernéticos.

Nota: Trampantojo es mencionado en el enlace que he puesto de la Fundéu, no es merito mío mencionarlo. Una gran palabra puesta de moda ultimamente por los programas de cocina. :-)

**[trampantojo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=aGlyc8T)**

> 1. m. coloq. **Trampa o ilusión con que se engaña** a alguien haciéndole ver lo que no es.

---

Contra:

Con **cibercebo** perdemos la palabra "clic", que es lo que se busca atraer, que hagamos clic en el enlace. Y aquí si entramos en la parte subjetiva. Click-cebo, cliccebo o cebo de clics no me parecen términos atractivos, no son bien sonantes, son complicados de escribir. Dos c's seguidas están pidiendo que se elimine una y se quede en clicebo y se pierda la separación nítida entre los términos constituyentes. Estas son apreciaciones totalmente personales, por supuesto. Di no a clicebo.

---

Resumiendo: **cazaclics** está muy bien, pero no despreciemos **cibercebo**.

Comment: ¿siempre se trata de links, verdad? Se podría pensar en usar la palabra `enlace` para combinar (en algo cómo 'enlace-trampa', 'enlace-anzuelo', etc

Comment: @ipp Vaya, ya no me acordaba de esta entrada. Se puede usar la palabra enlace, en efecto. Pero buscábamos una conexión más directa con el término anglosajón, en el cual no aparece el término link (enlace).